# User control localization C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization, webusercontrol

Default.aspx  localization I have created 
I have created

Default.aspx.en-IN.resx

Default.aspx.fr.resx

Default.aspx.resx

in **App_LocalResources** folder.
Code:

**Default.aspx**

```
 <asp:Label ID="Label1" meta:resourcekey="WelcomeString" 
                runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

**Default.aspx.cs**

```
    String selectedLanguage = Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["lang"]);
                UICulture = selectedLanguage;
                Culture = selectedLanguage;
 Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture =
                CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(selectedLanguage);
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new
                CultureInfo(selectedLanguage);
```

**localization works well.**

But now I want to create a user control and call it to default.aspx file.
How to do user control Localization in this method ? Please help...

Comment: If you explicitly set the UICulture and Culture, the controls normally adapt to the langugage. You just provide resx-files for the control too.

Comment: I have created

 <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Control.ascx.cs" Inherits="Controls_Control" %>

   <h2>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" meta:resourcekey="welcome" 
            runat="server"></asp:Label>
    
    </h2>

in App_LocalResources folder 

Control.ascx.fr.resx

I have added this user control to Default.aspx where I define culture in aspx.cs file

but its dosnt show any thing...